# Atoms attraction

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

Do atoms attract to atoms of same element? And would atoms attract to another atom for forming ionic or covalent bond? I basically want to know what would an atom be attracted to? (Except for ferromagnetism).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You're basically asking "do atoms form bonds", which is a really broad question, even though the answer could be as simple as "yes". I'm voting to close this.

Comment: @Daniel Griscom I actually wanted to know if there was anything other than electrostatic attraction among the atoms and also whether or not an atom could move(or travel some quantifiable distance) because of the electrostatic force.

Comment: If so, then you should add these details to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Basically “attraction” and “repulsion” are the result of the composed action of some kind of forces.

Regarding an atom-atom interaction, even if technically the gravitational attraction exists I assume in this discussion it can be neglected, hence basically you have just the electrostatic interaction as the dominant force.

Considering a couple of electrically neutral atoms let’s observe that their external electron shells will repel each other (however keep in mind that the atoms could get close enough despite this repulsion if they have enough kinetic energy)

Considering atomic ions, the electrostatic force can be attractive or repulsive according to ions charges

Comment: How strong would the electrostatic force be ? Could it make the ion move from its position ?Can it cause magnet like attraction?

Comment: How close do they have to be where gravity and electrostatic charge would both be a factor?

Comment: @user104591 What do you mean with “magnet like attraction” ? 

I suggest you to assume atoms / ions as points (so you are basically neglecting their internal geometry) and then to apply the Coulomb’s Law to compute the electrostatic force magnitude. The direction of the force vector is point-to-point.  

Whether the ion moves or not depends if it is in a bound state or not. 

A bound state is basically a negative potential well: if the force is not strong enough to make the ion cross the well barrier, then it does not move.

Comment: @Jens 
Now I am going by memory but speaking about orders of magnitude I think that at the atomic scale the Gravitational Force is about $ 10^{-37} $ compared to the Electrostatic Force